# If I download new version of Android Studio, do I have to manually uninstall previous one?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

In Android Studio, I got a notification an update was available. When I clicked `Download`, it took me to the [Download Page](https://developer.android.com/studio?utm_source=android-studio). I downloaded the new version. What should I do now in order to start using it? Do I need to manually uninstall the previous version and then just open the new version?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the download should have removed the previous version try closing all instances of android studio and then reopen it

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to uninstall manually, You can simply run the new installer and install the newest version over the older one.